# How to code an arduino to execute a particular code using a slide switch

Tags: programming, switch, input

I’m pretty new to arduino. I need help concerning a project I’m making. I’m using a SPDT slide switch to switch between what code(method) should be executed.i.e when I shift the switch to the left, XXX method should be executed and when I move the switch to the right, YYYY method should be executed. The center pin of the switch is connected to arduino +5v while the     left and right leg of the switch are connected like how a tactile switch is interfaces with the arduino. Please can anyone help me with the code, or at least how to program the arduino? Thank you[image: Here is the circuit connection]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your switch wiring for D12 is wrong. You connect your inputs directly to ground and that can never change, regardless of the position of the switch.

You effectively have:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHUnKG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However you are over complicating things.  A SPDT switch is nothing more than two buttons, only one of which can be pressed at one time.  If one is pressed the other *must* be released.

You can completely ignore half the switch and treat the other half as a button: if the "button" is pressed then the switch is in one position. If the "button" is released then it's in the other position.

Unless it's a "center off" switch, in which case it has 3 positions, not 2, and the middle one has nothing connected.

If it is a simple 2-position SPDT switch then just disconnect the D12 wire and remove the right-and resistor in your drawing. Then read D13 to determine the position: HIGH is one position and LOW is the other.

If it's a 3-position "center off" switch then move the D12 wire 4 holes to the left so that it connects to the switch-resistor junction, not ground. Then you will need to read both D12 and D13 - which ever one is HIGH is the one that is activated, and the switch is in that position.

Then it's a simple "if / else" (2 position) or "if / elseif / else" (3 position center-off) structure to decide which code to run.

Comment: “Your switch wiring for D12 is wrong. You connect your inputs directly to ground and that can never change, regardless of the position of the switch.”  I don’t understand how it is wrong, each side of the switch is basically like a push button, and that’s the exact same wiring as a push button.  I do agree with “However you are over complicating things. A SPDT switch is nothing more than two buttons, only one of which can be pressed at one time. If one is pressed the other must be released”. It’s a 2 position switch.

Comment: The method I first used did work but once I move the switch to one position, it won’t go back to its former position(as in not physically). I think maybe there’s a problem with the code.